# how to use `dlsym()` in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm a bit lost at making [`dlsym()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) work in Rust:

- [`libc::dlsym()`](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.80/libc/fn.dlsym.html) returns a `*mut c_void` handle to the desired function.
- To use that handle, I need to cast it to `extern fn`, but that doesn't seem possible, even though `fn` (`extern` or not) appears to be a `*mut` internally.
- If I store the handle as `*mut extern fn`, as I did in the sample program below, I'm effectively storing a `*mut` as a `*mut *mut` (see `gdb` output at the end), which, not surprisingly, will produce segfaults.

---

Sample program, which will segfault when `handle` is invoked at line 15:

```rs
use std::ffi::CString;

fn main() {
    let func_name = CString::new("fork").unwrap();

    let handle: *mut extern "C" fn() -> libc::pid_t =
        unsafe { libc::dlsym(libc::RTLD_NEXT, func_name.as_ptr()).cast() };

    if handle.is_null() {
        let error_msg = CString::new("dlsym(fork) failed: %s\n").unwrap();
        unsafe { libc::printf(error_msg.as_ptr(), libc::dlerror()) };
        panic!();
    }

    let pid = unsafe { (*handle)() };

    if pid == 0 {
        println!("parent pid = {}", unsafe { libc::getppid() });
    } else if pid == -1 {
        let error_msg = CString::new("fork() failed").unwrap();
        unsafe { libc::perror(error_msg.as_ptr()) };
    } else {
        println!("child pid = {}", pid);
    }
}
```

---

`gdb` output:

```rs
(gdb) p handle
$1 = (*mut *mut fn () -> i32) 0x7f40b093b900 <__libc_fork>
```

Comment: @Frxstrem It does. I guess I didn't look hard enough--sorry! For future readers: one potential problem is that [std::mem::transmute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.transmute.html) is "equivalent to `memcpy`" according to the official doc. I haven't verified that, but if it's true and you are shimming `memcpy()`, be ready to supply a backup implementation to avoid self-recursion.